# How to extract email id from a document using GATE's ANNIE plugin?

Tags: java, information-retrieval, gate, information-extraction

I am trying to extract Email's annotation sets using ANNIE. Email is a default annotation type provided by ANNIE.
I am using the following code:-

```
AnnotationSet defaultAnnotSet = doc.getAnnotations();
AnnotationSet curAnnSet;
curAnnSet = defaultAnnotSet.get("Email");
```

Here, i am getting the blank curAnnSet, don't know why

Comment: Does the `Document` you're looking at definitely contain any `Email` annotations?  Try processing the same document with the same application in the GATE Developer GUI and check what annotations are found.

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes there is no Email annotation provided by ANNIE

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be a little late but I don't think ANNIE provides an annotation "Email". I remember an annotation "Address". You will need to create a `JAPE` rule as below to extract its kind.

```
({Address.kind=email}):email
-->
:email.Email= {rule = "Email"}
```

or

Extract the annotations like this:

```
if(defaultAnnotSet.get("Address").getFeatures().get("kind").toString().equals("email"))
{ 
//create new features
features.put("rule", "Email");

// create new annotation                                   
outputAS.add(defaultAnnotSet.firstNode(), defaultAnnotSet.lastNode(), "Email", features);

    }
```